# "within five business days of month end"

Tags: legalese, dates

Does "within five business days of month end" mean something that is done within 5 business days after the month has ended, or does it mean the last 5 business days of the month?

EDIT: In regards to the suggested thread for answering, I believe the wording here makes it a different situation as the other thread seems much more clear.

Calling this wording bureaucratese does seem to fit the bill perfectly.

As for asking others within my organization, that may help if I get lucky with the right person but I find that I spend much more time learning and worrying about these small details than other people.

Comment: Given that it should read *the end of the month*, and not *month end*, it was probably written by a non-native English speaker. You would need to look at what the corresponding phrase means in their native language; the word *within* is ambiguous in English.

Comment: I don't believe it was made by a non-native speaker as it is from a government manual. Allow me to provide the paragraph to add more context:

E. Reviewing monthly extracts to ensure asset listing in Oracle FAM is correct and
complete in accordance with program listing and/or subsidiary system listing. Report the status of this review including planned acquisitions and disposals to Commandant
(CG-844) and FINCEN (FR) within five business days of month end;

Comment: So maybe *month end* is some kind of bureaucratese, which the rest of the passage is also written in. It's certainly not the standard English phrasing. [See Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=end+of+the+month%2C+month+end&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: Assuming the monthly extracts are done and reviewed at the end of the month, you have five days to report. So your report is due by the 5th of the month.

Comment: That sounds like an agency  I worked for in France who paid their invoices: à 45 jours fin de mois. So, if is September 1, you counted 45 days as of the end of September. They got away with it too even though it is illegal in the EU to pay that late.

Answer (score 2):

You've provided the full quote:

> Reviewing monthly extracts to ensure asset listing in Oracle FAM is correct and complete in accordance with program listing and/or subsidiary system listing. Report the status of this review including planned acquisitions and disposals to Commandant (CG-844) and FINCEN (FR) within five business days of month end;

Presumably, if the "monthly extracts" are generated at the end of each month, the phrase means "at most five business days *after* the end of the month." After all, you can't review the "extracts" until they've been produced.

That said, you might want to talk to someone with more experience in this domain.